# Difficulties creating an action that fetches data with React Redux and axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I've taken this weekend to learn Redux but I can't understand how I can make API calls using **axios**, **Redux** and **Redux Thunk**

I've deleted everything from this sample project so that there's only one action: the one from which I want to get my data.

[Here's the link to my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-black-z8e64?file=/src/store/actions/actions.js)

I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly easy but I can't figure out what it is.
If someone could help me or point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it

**My reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = { ...state };

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SOMETHING':
      newState.data = action.data;
      console.log(newState.data);
      break;
    default:
      newState;
  }
  return newState;
};

export default reducer;
```

**My Action**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function someFunction() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/types').then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SOMETHING', data: response.data });
    });
  };
}
```

**My App.js**

```
function App({ someFunction }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={someFunction}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    data: state.data,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    something: () => dispatch(actionCreator.someFunction()),
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: You need to refer the prop `name` as what you have returned in `mapDispatchToProps`, not with the actual action creator function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there! The problems is here:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    something: () => dispatch(actionCreator.someFunction()),
  };
};
```

You're telling redux to map `dispatch` actions to props called `{ something }`. You need to either rename the prop to `something` or rename the map to `someFunction`.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    someFunction: () => dispatch(actionCreator.someFunction()),
  };
};
```

Comment: @ItzaMi, a small addition to the above with `object short hand` notation, `const mapDispatchToProps = { someFunction: actionCreator.someFunction };`. You can declare simple actions like this. Check [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops) for more details

Comment: Thank you, @Cehhiro, I can't believe I didn't see that. Today was my first dip into Redux and the amount of concepts has been too much but I appreciate your quick reply!

Comment: I have a new question, @Cehhiro.
How could I populate my state with an initial call of axios right when the page loads?